# Atributo download en <a> me descarga el archivo, pero también mi página

Tags: php

Tengo en mi página "descargas.php" la siguiente línea:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.replace('uploads/ejemplo.pdf');" download>
```

Por temas de privacidad, estoy usando el onclick para que el usuario no vea el enlace original donde está alojado el archivo, sino que se descargue de inmediato (se que no es el mejor método en seguridad).

El problema es que al dar clic, no sólo se descarga el archivo "ejemplo.pdf", sino que también me descarga como un archivo mi página "descargas.php"

Existe un método para evitar esto?
Me recomiendan otro método para ocultar la ruta del archivo?

---

### **EDITO**

Estoy usando el atributo `download` por los archivos pdf que Chrome visualiza en lugar de descargar, gracias por aclarar que si quito este atributo elimino el error comentando al inicio

Comment: Puedes usar una llamada Ajax en la cual, desde el cliente envías la información del archivo, en el servidor recoges esa info, armas la URL y provocas una descarga directa del archivo, sea mediante `cURL` sea mediante `readfile` poniendo los encabezados requeridos. Si te interesa hacerlo así puedo proponer un código.

Comment: Claro, me interesaría ver la forma en que implementarías tu código.

Comment: Haz probado con la función location.assign()

Comment: si es por seguridad con apretar ver descargas ya te muestra la url, no hace falta ver el source del html

Comment: No había pensado en eso alo Malbarez, y tienes razón. Ya tengo un problema más por resolver :c

Comment: Si tu problema es que quieres ocultar la url, podrías implementar un sistema de generación de url's temporales que oculten las reales. Te puedes guardar en una tabla una relación de los enlaces temporales con los reales y la hora en la que se han creado para saber si son válidos cuando te lleguen la peticiones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Me voy a basar en un escenario cualquiera, lo más parecido a lo que propones sería por ejemplo una lista de archivos que se ofrecen en descarga y que, según tú, quieres ocultar la url donde están esos archivos.

Pondremos esa lista en forma de link, escucharemos los clicks en cada uno de ellos y lanzaremos desde el cliente una petición al servidor para que la descarga se haga directamente, que es lo que requieres.

Desde el cliente vamos a lanzar una petición `XMLHttpRequest` al servidor, mandándole la ubicación del archivo. Indicaremos que se espera una respuesta del tipo `blob` y a partir de la respuesta podremos descargar el archivo.

> **MUY IMPORTANTE:**
>
> La información sobre el nombre y ubicación de cada archivo se
>   encuentra en el atributo `data-*` de cada `li`, como se podrá apreciar
>   en el código fuente HMTL.
>
> Aquí suponemos que los los siguientes archivos existen en tu servidor:
>
> ```
>  uploads
>      pdf
>        android.pdf
>        js.pdf
>        php.pdf
>
>     doc
>        swift.doc
>
>     txt
>        cobol.txt
> ```

El archivo si existe se descargará en el equipo del cliente, sin mostrar en ningún momento el enlace del recurso.

Es conveniente controlar la respuesta de la petición `XMLHttpRequest`, por ejemplo, en caso de no existir el archivo, para hacer un manejo adecuado del código.

No lo he hecho por razones de brevedad.

El código ha sido probado en un entorno real y funciona.

Espero te sirva.

#### JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  /*Referencias a los elementos*/
  var liFiles = document.querySelectorAll('.list-files li');
  var divInfo = document.getElementById("info");

  /*Agregamos listener a todos los <li>*/
  liFiles.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', downloadFile, false);
  });

  /*
     *Esta es la función que se ejecutará cada vez que
     *se haga click en alguno de los <li>
  */
  function downloadFile() {
    /*
       *Obtenemos el directorio, el nombre
       *y construimos una ruta completa
    */
    var fileDir = this.dataset.dir;
    var fileName = this.dataset.name;
    var filePath = `${fileDir}/${fileName}`;

    /*Vamos a hacer una petición al servidor buscando el archivo*/
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", filePath, true);
        req.responseType = "blob";
        req.onload = function(event) {
            var blob = req.response;
            /*
              *Aquí hacemos que el archivo se descargue
              *sin ninguna acción
            */
            var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = fileName;
                link.click();
        };

        req.send();

    /*Imprimimos un mensaje*/
    divInfo.textContent = "Archivo descargado... Conviene validar la respuesta y manejar posibles errores.";
  }

});
```

---

#### HMTL:

```
<h2>Archivos disponibles</h2>
<hr />
<ul class="list-files">
  <li data-dir="uploads/pdf" data-name="android.pdf"><a id="ff" href="#">Android</a></li>
  <li data-dir="uploads/doc" data-name="swift.doc"><a href="#">Swift</a></li>
  <li data-dir="uploads/pdf" data-name="js.pdf"><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
  <li data-dir="uploads/pdf" data-name="php.pdf"><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
  <li data-dir="uploads/txt" data-name="cobol.txt"><a href="#">Cobol</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Fantástico, no era el camino que buscaba en principio, pero me ha servido para llegar al mismo punto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Quisiera implementar las descargas dentro de una tabla en lugar de una lista, debo tener algo a consideración? Pido disculpas si esta no es la forma de hacer la consulta

Comment: Lo único que cambiaría prácticamente sería esto: `var liFiles = document.querySelectorAll('.list-files li');`. Lo que se hace ahí es seleccionar los `<li>` que están dentro de un contenedor cuya clase es `list-files`. Tendrías por ejemplo que hacer lo mismo con la tabla: `<table class="list-files">` y alcanzar los `<tr>` o los `<td>` como se ha hecho con los `<li>`. Y poner los atributos `data-*` también igual.

Comment: Mil gracias, no puedo pedir más, me funciona perfecto!

Answer (score 2):

Es por el atributo download que has puesto. Quítalo

Comment: Es muy cierta tu observación, pero edito mi pregunta para aclarar dudas.