# ¿Cómo mostrar un PDF mediante una ruta en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en `index.php` donde se muestran unos cuantos campos:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 style="text-align:center">Registro de colaborador</h2>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-hover display" id="mitabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th scope="col">Correo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Documento</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    <?php
                        include "conexion.php";
                        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM personas";
                        $resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
                        while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                            echo "<td>"; echo $fila['id']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $fila['nombre']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $fila['correo']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $fila['documento']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como se muestra en la columna **documento**, ahí tengo almacenada en MySQL la ruta de un archivo PDF.

[image: index.php en el navegador]

Y quiero saber cómo puedo enlazar un botón para descargar el PDF mediante la ruta:

[image: index.php con botones]

El archivo de `conexion.php` es:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'personal');

if($mysqli->connect_error){

    die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);

}
?>
```

Intenté primero obteniendo el `id` del registro:

```
echo "<td><a href='descargar.php?id=".$fila['id']."'> <button type='button' class= 'btn btn-outline-success'>Acta PDF</button></a></td>";
```

Después, en un nuevo archivo llamado `descargar.php` una consulta:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

include "conexion.php";

$documento = $mysqli->query("SELECT acta FROM personas WHERE id=$id");
```

Había usado `opendir()` y `readdir()`, pero no me funcionó.

La tabla personas tiene 4 columnas:

- `id`
- `nombre`
- `correo`
- `documento`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error o problema? ¿`descargar.php` gestiona bien la descarga del archivo? ¿Por qué le pasas el `id`, siendo que al parecer la ruta del archivo se encuentra en la columna `documento`? Podrías armar también la descarga desde código Javascript, así no tienes que volver al servidor.

Comment: En descargar.php probé primero con un var_dump() para ver si podía pasarse el id, sí lo hizo. Le paso el id cuando le doy en el botón "Acta PDF" y de ahí hago la consulta para obtener la ruta que está almacenada en la columna documento, pero de ahí ya no avancé más aunque intenté aplicar el opendir y readdir, pero supongo que no supe cómo aplicarlo realmente @A.Cedano

Comment: Entiendo, pero, pregunto: ¿cuando creas la tabla ya tienes toda la información, incluida la ruta de descarga del PDF? En ese caso puedes hacer la descarga desde el cliente (Javascript), sin tener que volver al servidor. [Aquí hay un ejemplo basado en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/202118/29967).

Comment: Sí, es decir, es parte de un proyecto donde en otro archivo hay una tabla y un botón de "Nuevo", el registro tanto de los campos como la subida del archivo pdf lo almacena bien, ahí no tengo problema, el problema es cuando quiero poner un botón para descargar dicho archivo cuando tengo la ruta donde se encuentra ese archivo en la base de datos @A.Cedano

Comment: [Mira este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/202118/29967) donde se crean enlaces dinámicos de descarga vía Javascript. Puedes implementar algo parecido. Sería poner una clase a cada botón y luego asignarles un listener que obtenga la URL de descarga y lance la descarga del PDF.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda @A.Cedano

Comment: Ángeles, ¿es completamente necesario que los usuarios pasen por `descargar.php`? Te puedo proponer una forma de realizar el mismo trabajo ahorrándote usar un script intermediario de descarga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probaste con `readfile`? Más específicos, en tu archivo `descargar.php`:

```php
$id = $_GET['id'];

include "conexion.php";

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT documento FROM personas WHERE id=$id");
$fila = $res->fetch_assoc();

$rutaArchivo = $fila['documento']; // Obtenemos la ruta al archivo de tu BD
$nombreArchivo = basename($rutaArchivo); // Con la ruta extraemos el nombre del archivo

// Headers necesarios para forzar la descarga del PDF en vez de mostrarlo al navegador
// si deseas el efecto contrario puedes quitarlos
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$nombreArchivo");

// Leemos el archivo PDF y mandamos a la salida
readfile($rutaArchivo);
```

Algo así.

Comment: funcionó, muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Si no es estrictamente necesario hacer pasar a los usuarios por un script intermedio para realizar la descarga del archivo PDF, sobre todo si no se aplican ACLs, podrías incluir el enlace al PDF en la propia tabla:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
/* Realizamos la consulta al comienzo del script */
$consulta = 'SELECT * FROM personas';
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
if ($resultado === false) {
  die(htmlspecialchars('Error SQL:'. $mysqli->error));
}
?><div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">Registro de colaborador</h2>
  </div>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover display" id="mitabla">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th scope="col">Correo</th>
          <th scope="col">Documento</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php while ($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila['id']) ?></td>
          <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila['nombre']) ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="mailto:<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['correo']) ?>">
              <?= htmlspecialchars($fila['correo']) ?>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a style="appearance: button;"
                href="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['documento']) ?>">
              Acta PDF
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

De esta manera la sobrecarga en el servidor será inferior que la ejecución de un PHP para pasar a través de él el contenido del archivo hasta el usuario.

Además, fíjate bien el uso que hago de [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars) para evitar [vulnerabilidades XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) en tu página. Todo texto enviado al navegador debe ser escapado correctamente.

Comment: No lo había pensado de esa forma, gracias, intentaré hacer la prueba con lo que me has dado.

Comment: Acabo de corregir un pequeño error en la comprobación del resultado de la consulta (puse los dos puntos fuera de la cadena de caracteres).